# How do I log errors from a powershell script called by a SQL stored procedure into a SQL table?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, stored-procedures

I have a SQL stored procedure that executes a powershell file, and I want to log any errors that occur executing the powershell file into a SQL table.

My SQL stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_RemoveEmptyFiles]
    @filePath varchar(260)

AS 

DECLARE @sql as varchar(4000)
DECLARE @powershellFileLocation varchar(260)

SET @powershellFileLocation = '\\MyComputerName\Files\Powershell\cleandirectory.ps1'


SET @sql = 'powershell -c "& { . ' + @powershellFileLocation + '; clean-directory ' + @filePath + ' }"'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

My powershell script:

```
function clean-directory {
    param ([string]$path)
    try 
    {
        if ($path.Length -le 0 -or -not (test-path -literalPath $path)) {
            throw [System.IO.FileNotFoundException] """$path"" not a valid file path."
        }

        #
        #
        # Clean directories here
        #
        #
    }
    catch 
    {
        write-host $error
    }
}
```

Right now, if the script is successful, it returns an output of `NULL` and a Return Value of 0. The goal is to replace that catch block with something that will save those errors to a SQL table.

My first (inefficient) thought is to then invoke a SQL command in that catch block, something like:

```
$commandText = "INSERT INTO ErrorLogTable (TimeStamp, ErrorMessage) VALUES ($(Get-Date), $error)"
$command = $conn.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = $commandText
$command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

But this hardly seems like the best way to do it-- connecting back to the SQL server the stored procedure was called from and creating a new command, etc. It should be noted that the powershell script, file path argument of the stored procedure, and SQL server are in different locations, so I do need to keep permission issues in mind (and hence why I am trying to avoid calling `Invoke-Sqlcmd` from my powershell script).

Is there a way to get the output of the powershell file in the stored procedure, and then save the error message into a table from there?

Comment: I suggest you alter your powershell to output to the console then use this method to capture it. https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic188738-9-1.aspx It's bad design to have two components that independently call each other like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using `xp_cmdshell`, I can capture that output by changing the SQL script as follows:

```
SET @sql = 'powershell -c "& { . ' + @powershellFileLocation + '; clean-directory ' + @filePath + ' }"'

-- table to hold the output from the cmdshell
CREATE TABLE #PowershellOutput ([Output] varchar(1000))

-- execute actual powershell script
INSERT INTO #PowershellOutput ([Output]) EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

This captures each line sent to the console as a separate row. It's not the best solution for capturing error messages from powershell, so I'm still looking for a better way to capture them. I'll either join these rows to a single output, or find a better way to capture only the powershell error (as opposed to the entire stacktrace).